# How to add GridViewColumnHeader to GridViewColumn dynamically?

Tags: wpf, gridview, gridviewcolumn

Hi I am creating `GridView` column dynamically like this:

```
GridViewColumn idColumn = new GridViewColumn();
grdMain.Columns.Add(idColumn).
```

Now I want to attach `ColumHeader` to create the column dynamically. I did:

```
GridViewColumnHeader idColumnHeader = new GridViewColumnHeader();
```

Now how can I attach this `Header` to `idColumn`?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set the Header property, like

```
idColumn.Header = idColumnHeader;
```